# String Comparison in LINQ to SQL result null

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, linq, string-comparison

I have two string array and want to see if there are any intersection or not. I am using linq to sql in c# and fetch the database field and compare it with the user input as below :

```
string[] Materials = material.Split('-');
AllItems = (from item in AllItems
            where item.Material.Split(',').Intersect(Materials).Count() != 0
            select item).ToList();
```

Materials are user input string which has - delimiter and in database I have string with `,` delimiter.

I wonder why the result is always null. I mean the query result says there is no intersection but I check and there is.

Another alternative query that I used and take the same result was this :

```
string[] Materials = material.Split('-');
HashSet<string> stringSet = new HashSet<string>(Materials);
AllItems = (from item in AllItems
            where item.Color.Split(',').Where(c => stringSet.Contains(c)).Count() != 0
            select item).ToList();
```

I am so confused whats the problem with these queries. I should mention that the strings are UTF8 one and contains 2 bytes character in persian language, I guess maybe It's the problem but I don't know how to solve it.

Is there any solutions?

UPDATE (AllItems and Example) :

```
List<Item> AllItems = (from item in db.Items
                       select item).ToList();
```

- Example of material => "ابی-قرمز-زرد"
- Example of Item.Material => "ابی,سبز"

Update (Local Test) :

I test the same linq in some local string and using linq to object and the answer is correct !!! but in linq to sql and server string it always says that nothing found ! whats the problem?

Comment: Can you show examples of the values of `material` and `item.Material`?

Comment: @juharr I add them to the question.

Comment: Well for those values it seems like the splits and intersection you did should have worked.  What exactly do you mean by "the results is always null"?  I would expect that you might get an empty `List<Item>` if no matches are found, but not a `null`.

Comment: @juharr I get no matches are found while there are match in the strings, like the example the first strings match but the result count is zero !

Comment: All I can suggest is that you rewrite that Linq as a `foreach` like `foreach(var item in AllItems) { var itemMaterials = item.Material.Split(','); var intersect = itemMaterials.Intersect(Materials).ToList(); ...}` and debug it to verify the values in the `Materials` and `itemMaterials` arrays to see if there should be an intersection and then what the result of `Intersect` is.

Comment: @juharr thanks, I will do this, but it is too slow rather than the linq, isn't it?

Comment: I'm suggesting it as a way to easily debug and see what's going on primarily.  But no it would not be slower. It should have roughly the same performance as that's more or less what the Linq code would end up doing.

Comment: Shot in the dark but maybe because of the language the intersect needs something like "StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase"?       where item.Material.Split(',').Intersect(Materials, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).Count() != 0

Comment: @AlecMenconi thanks for your comment, I've tried all of this things and finally find out one of the Item's Color attribute is null and cause exception and return null !!! thanks all of you guys.

Comment: Excellent, glad you figured it out.

Comment: @Evil make sure you answer your own question with what you found and mark it as the answer to help others who find your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that, One of the Item's Color attribute was null and cause exception and return null. so I add a check to be not null before split and it works.

thanks all of you guys.